# Convert column names as a list in R

Tags: r

For a given dataframe `df`, I want get all column names as list split by comma. What I need is like this: `"observation_date", "TERMCBAUTO48NS", "BAA10YM", "AAA10YM"...`

How can I do that? Thank you.

The following code doesn't generate what I need:

```
list(colnames(df))
```

Out:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "observation_date" "TERMCBAUTO48NS"  
 [3] "BAA10YM"          "AAA10YM"         
 [5] "TB3SMFFM"         "T5YFFM"          
 [7] "T10Y2YM"          "BAA"             
 [9] "AAA"              "TERMCBCCALLNS"   
[11] "MPRIME"           "TWEXBMTH"        
[13] "M1SL"             "M2SL"            
[15] "RMFSL"            "SVSTCBSL"        
[17] "BORROW"           "SEABORR"         
[19] "GDBFRM"           "DDDFCBNS"        
[21] "TSDFBOI"          "REQRESNS"        
[23] "DPCERA3M086SBEA"  "PSAVERT"         
[25] "DTTHFM"           "DTRTM"           
[27] "IPMAN"            "IPCONGD"         
[29] "CPIAUCSL"         "CPIHOSSL"        
[31] "CSUSHPINSA"       "FEDFUNDS"        
[33] "UNRATE"           "INDPRO"          
[35] "RECPROUSM156N"    "HOUST"           
[37] "SPASTT01USM661N"  "CP"
```

Comment: `toString(colnames(df))` ?

Comment: `paste(dQuote(colnames(df)), collapse = ", ")`

Comment: @Clemsang, your solution works just fine, thank a lot. You may post your solution as answer if you like to.

Comment: @RonakShah sorry `''` which are necessary but missing with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dQuote`:

```
paste(dQuote(colnames(df)), collapse = ", ")
"“n”, “s”, “b”"
```